# Can't open a button in my emulator

Tags: android

I have 14 buttons, and one of them doesn't open. It used to open, but now it gives me an error, and closes the application when I click on it. I know there must be something I coded wrong. I'm watching the LogCat but I can't take anything out of that.

This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Bezoek"
    android:background="@drawable/rkzafbeelding"> 


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo"
        android:layout_gravity="left" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:src="@drawable/informatiebutton" />
 </FrameLayout>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/title_activity_bezoek"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
         android:textColor="@color/black"
    />



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="244dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Klik hier voor de uitgebreide bezoektijden."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

This is my LogCat:

```
06-21 06:50:45.595: D/dalvikvm(316): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 80K, 51% free 2664K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 104ms
06-21 06:50:47.015: D/dalvikvm(316): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 4K, 51% free 2686K/5379K, external 15420K/15441K, paused 40ms
06-21 06:50:50.015: D/dalvikvm(316): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 11K, 50% free 2716K/5379K, external 15712K/17696K, paused 90ms
06-21 06:50:50.045: E/dalvikvm-heap(316): 12050168-byte external allocation too large for this process.
06-21 06:50:50.085: E/GraphicsJNI(316): VM won't let us allocate 12050168 bytes
06-21 06:50:50.085: D/dalvikvm(316): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 50% free 2715K/5379K, external 15712K/17696K, paused 26ms
06-21 06:50:50.085: D/skia(316): --- decoder->decode returned false
06-21 06:50:50.085: D/AndroidRuntime(316): Shutting down VM
06-21 06:50:50.085: W/dalvikvm(316): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rodekruis/com.example.rodekruis.BezoekActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at com.example.rodekruis.BezoekActivity.onCreate(BezoekActivity.java:25)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  ... 11 more
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  ... 21 more
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1899)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:286)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:120)
06-21 06:50:50.125: E/AndroidRuntime(316):  ... 24 more
06-21 06:50:52.845: I/Process(316): Sending signal. PID: 316 SIG: 9
```

Every help is appreciated.

Comment: Button doesn't open? Open what? You are getting OutOfMemory error. You must be loading large size images in your app upon that button click. Try compressing them.

Comment: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` this error is loud and clear in your logcat! do some research on how to handle BitMap in Android

Comment: BezoekActivity.java:25   what is at this line ------You have any image which is large in size so it causing outofmemoryError and app is crashing

Comment: But on my homepage, I have the exact same image, and it shows there. Does that mean I'm not capable of using the same image on every page? Because I don't have the memory for that?

Comment: I've deleted the image from the layout and it works now. But again, does that mean I'm not able to put in an image as a background beside my homepage?

Answer (score 1):

In your `LinearLayout` the `android:background="@drawable/rkzafbeelding"` cause the error. and also Give `OutOfMemory` error make sure that The `Image` size is not large. and for better performance use below code in `Manifest.xml` file.

```
<application
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
       >
```

Comment: `largeHeap`should only be used if absolutely necessary. only do this for too big image is not a good way....

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any on click functionality, what exactly do you mean 'opened'?

```
android:onClick="OtherActivity"
```

Comment: The click functionality is in the Main Activity, this is the layout activity.